# What is the feedback signal used in the speed control of a brushless DC motor?

Tags: motors, torque, sensors, feedback-loop

In a [brush-less DC (BLDC) motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor) the commonly used speed is sensed using the feedback from [Hall effect sensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall-effect_sensor) and [the back or counter EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force). The linked article on Wikipedia also mentions that 'Other sensorless controllers are capable of measuring winding saturation caused by the position of the magnets to infer the rotor position.'.

> Are these the only possible sensors used to sense the speed? Additionally, how can we estimate the load torque in a practical and commercially available BLDC motor?

Comment: Are you wanting speed or load? They are different.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for bringing the lack of clarity in the text of the question to my attention. I have edited the question to reflect the intent accurately. I would like to know sensors other than Hall and back EMF for speed estimation as well as possibly those for load torque estimation.

Comment: I believe current sensors might work too.

Comment: Motor control tends to get covered at the EE StackExchange. Here is a [search for BLDC speed control](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=BLDC+speed+control) from there